# Creating an indicator vector

Tags: matlab

I have an array (`A`) containing n elements. I know B is `0:10*n`. I would like `B` to be 1 when element `B(i)` is in `A` and 0 otherwise. I am currently doing this with:

```
A = [2,5,6]
n = size(A,2)
B = zeros(1,10*n+1)
for i = 0:(10*n)
     B(i+1) = ismember(i,A);
end
```

However, I am trying to do this in O(nlog(n)) time or faster. Is there any information on the speed of `ismember`? Is there a faster way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No need for the (slow) for loop, as [`ismember`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) can be called on vectors, as shown below

```
% Sample data
n = 10000;
A = randi([0,10*n],1,n);

% Slow for loop
tic
B = zeros(1,10*n+1);
for i = 0:(10*n)
     B(i+1) = ismember(i,A);
end
toc

% Fast, vectorized version
tic
C = ismember(0:10*n, A);
toc
```

Resulting in

```
Elapsed time is 5.791429 seconds.

Elapsed time is 0.012246 seconds.
```

which is a speed-up of almost factor 500. I can't tell you what computational complexity this has, but it is certainly a lot faster than the for-loop version.